# writing tests for robots.txt (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, robots.txt

Dealing with robots isn't something I have much experience in. So I feel that I'd like to write some tests to check that my robots.txt file is doing what I want.

Is there a standard (or any) way to write tests to check if the Disallow rules are working as intended?

Clarification-edit:
by tests I mean rspec controller specs that can behave as if they were from a robot and then assert that the response was either allowed or blocked.

Comment: Google webmaster tools is the standard way to analyse your robots.txt.  You'll need to get your site online, eg in its "staging" environment as i don't think you can connect to a locally running app from Webmaster (unless you have your network set up to have your machine as the http gateway)

Comment: thanks @MaxWilliams I've setup webmaster now. but I was more wondering about writing controller specs that could act as if the request was a robot and then assert the response was either allowed or blocked.

Comment: I've never seen anyone automate robots.txt testing into their test spec i'm afraid.  Sounds like a cool thing to do though, good luck :)